# Looking for Woocommerce bulk pricing quantity ranges database table

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm importing a Wordpress database into my own database and I need to match wordpress tables and columns to my database tables and columns. I need to find the woocommerce bulk pricing quantity ranges and prices.

I've checked all Woocommerce tables starting with `wp_woocommerce…` and the `wp_posts` table and a bunch of others but I can't find them. The normal prices are in `wp_postmeta` where `meta_key` like "%price%" but the quantity ranges don't seem to be in this table.

On WooCommerce > status under "active plugins" it says WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing & Discounts -> RightPress

At Woocommerce > Pricing and Discounts i see this:

[image: Bulk pricing by quantity]

which is the info i'm trying to find

And you can see the result [**here**](https://abadiarural.pt/loja/frascos-ou-vasos/marinate-210cc-to66/?v=35357b9c8fe4).

Comment: How people can guess what you are asking: you should mention that you are using a third party plugin that extend WooCommerce product prices and quantities… As most plugin general (or global) settings, this should be on `wp_options` table.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have no idea what plugins this thing is using, I'm very unfamiliar with wordpress, i'm just trying to get the info out of it that I need. the wp_options table has option_id, option_name, option_value and autoload. How does this associate to the products? And how do I find what I need in this? Thanks

Comment: By default in WooCommerce **there is NO** Pricing and discounts page > Bulk pricing by quantity settings. So please go in WooCommerce Status section and find out which plugin is enabled that handle bulk pricing on quantity ranges, then edit your question. Remember that ***"Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers"***.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec it says WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing & Discounts and then RightPress

Comment: So better try to contact [RightPress support pages for WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing & Discounts plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-dynamic-pricing-discounts/7119279/support) and ask them, as this is a commercial non official plugin.

Answer (score 0):

it's here: `select * from wp_options where option_name like "%rp_wcdpd_settings%"`